# Remap git colors

Tags: git, git-config

I know I can change the color for specific things in the .gitconfig, such as:

```
[color "diff"]
    old = brightred
    new = brightgreen
```

That solves most of the cases I care about, but I'd like a more general remap where every `red` becomes `brightred`, and every `green` becomes `brightgreen`, which are easier to read for me on a black background.

Is that possible?

Comment: For such general remappings it's probably better to just tweak the color palette of your terminal. Most terminal emulators support configuring the colors (or even outright support color themes).

Comment: Yes, I though about it.  But I'm not sure I want to remap every red and green to their bright variants.  For example, I use red in vim for the right margin, and don't want it to be bright... I'd have to think about it, but thanks, anyway

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to custom your color as you want .
you can follow this [article](https://coderwall.com/p/3hp3cw/custom-coloring-using-gitconfig) to custom your color

Comment: Yes, I know I can go through every git element and change its color, but that's too cumbersome, and not very future-proof.  But I think I'll do that, and restrict myself to the things I mostly use, and leave corner cases with their default colors.